# I would like to print "subscription successful" when I click on the join button

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

HTML code:

```
<div class="small-3 columns">
    <input type="submit" id="join" class="button postfix  " value="Join &raquo;">
    <span id="error"></span>
</div>
```

I am using jQuery ajax post data method to print "Subscription successful" when user clicks on join button.

jQuery code:index.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#join").click(function() {
            var vemail = $("#emailaddy").val();
            if(vemail=='') {
                alert("Please enter email address");
            } else {
                $.post("join.php", //Required URL of the page on server
                {   
                    // Data Sending With Request To Server
                    emailaddy:vemail
                },
                /*function(response,status){  // Required Callback Function
                    alert("*----Received Data----*\n\nResponse : " + response+"\n\nStatus : " + status);//"response"  receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
                    $("#form")[0].reset();
                });*/
            }
            $("#error").text("hello");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have created another page which is requested by index.php.

```
<?php
if($_POST["emailaddy"])
{
    $email = $_POST["emailaddy"];
    // Here, you can also perform some database query operations with above values.
   echo "Welcome ". $email ."!"; // Success Message
}
?>
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: in php file `if(isset($_POST["emailaddy"]))` try

Answer (score 0):

You can uncomment this

```
/*function(response,status){  // Required Callback Function
alert("*----Received Data----*\n\nResponse : " + response+"\n\nStatus : " + status);//"response"  receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
$("#form")[0].reset();
```

and if the response is true show a div with a "Subscription successful" text-message.

Answer (score 0):

Close `$.post()` method properly.And set subscription message from function inside post method.Like this..

```
 $.post("join.php", //Required URL of the page on server
    {   // Data Sending With Request To Server
    emailaddy:vemail
    },
    function(response,status){
    alert(response);//alerts welcome email..
    $("#error").text("Subscription successful");
    $("#form")[0].reset();
    });*/
```

Comment: thank you for your assistance. Now I am able to see "Subscription successful" message but after 2-3 seconds page is being reloaded automatically.

Comment: my problem is not solved yet. Page is being reloaded after 2-3 seconds.

Comment: are you using `location.href` anywhere.

Comment: Remove `action` attribute from form tag.because you done your action using ajax.

Comment: don;t forget to set `type="post" ` inside `form` tag.

Comment: I am not using location.href and action attribute.Still I am getting issue.

Comment: what is your issue.could post it on comment.

Comment: when i click on the join button "subscription successful" message appears but after 2-3 seconds page is being reloaded automatically.

Comment: in console, I am getting "failed to load resources" error.

Comment: where is your `join.php` file?place it within same folder.

Comment: it is in the same folder.

Comment: in php file `if(isset($_POST["emailaddy"]))` try

Answer (score 0):

First of all make a file named functions.php if you dont have one.
Then make a function **SetFormMsg($msg)** and one **ViewFormMsg()**.

Code:

```
function SetFormMsg($msg) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
    }
    $_SESSION['formMsg'] = $msg;
}

function ViewFormMsg() {
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['formMsg'])
    {
        $message = $_SESSION['formMsg'];
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "";
    }
    return $message
}
```

and in your html code at the end of the form make a  element that contains:

*If you want all of these to work include the '**functions.php**' at the beginning of both html and php/sql documents.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#join").click(function(){
        var vemail = $("#emailaddy").val();
        if(vemail=='')
        {
            alert("Please enter email address");
        }
        else{
            $.post( "join.php",{ 'emailaddy': vemail})
                .done(function( data ) {
                    $("#error").html(data);
                    $("#success").html('Subscription successful');
                });
        }

    });
});
</script>
<div class="small-3 columns">
  <span id="success"></span>
  <input type="email" name="emailaddy" id="emailaddy">
  <input type="submit" id="join" class="button postfix  " value="Join &raquo;">
  <span id="error"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the response is success you can use **.html instead of .text**

$("#error").html("Subscription successful"); for $("#error").text("Subscription successful");